# Cannot Split Diff Output to Array

Tags: bash, jq

I have not really used bash for something this complicated before so pardon very simple mistakes.

So I am trying to split the output of a diff into array by doing the following :

```
diffresult=$(diff <(jq . actualProp.json) <(jq . standardProp.json) | tr -d '<>-')
echo $diffresult #returns 2c2 "access": "Deny", "access": "Allow", 5c5 "destinationPortRange": "33899", "destinationPortRange": "3389", 8c8 "priority": 3009, "priority": 300,

#split diffresult into array 
IFS=',' read -ra array <<< "$diffresult"

#check the length
echo "${#array[@]}" #returns 1

#loop through the array
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
  echo "$element" 
done
#returns 2c2
```

What am I doing wrong, why cant I split the output of the diff into an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> echo $diffresult

Unquoted results of expansions undergo word splitting expansion. As a general rule, when you write `$` it should be inside `"`.

> IFS=',' read -ra array <<< "$diffresult"

`read` reads until the first newline. It then splits *one line* on `IFS` and assigns the result to arguments. As such, your `read` reads only the first line `2c2`.

You may want to use `bash` extension and read lines:

```
readarray -t array <<<"$diffresult"
```

Research [how to read a stream line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) , [how to load lines from a stream to an array](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Loading_lines_from_a_file_or_stream) and [about quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).